# How to display tiled huge image

Tags: android, google-maps, tile

I want to display a huge image from a server on an Android device. 
The image should be zoomable, when I zoom to some point, the app should display appropriate tail in better quality. 
It should behave exactly like Google Maps.

Can I use custom TileProvider from Google Maps to do that? Unfortunately, my image isn't related with maps, it's just a huge photo (additionally it isn't square). How do you recalculate geo location points with zoom to my tile position? 
I thought about creating my own view but I'm afraid of problems with memory. What is the best approach to do it?